# Scene where cartoon boy cools down thermometer to prove he’s not sick

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This has been bothering me for years but there was this show I watched when I was a kid and I remember one specific scene from an episode where there was the main character boy, and he was sick with a fever, so someone (his best friend or sister idk) said he couldn’t join a mission so he used ice powers to make the thermometer read cooler?? He like froze it or something idk please help I’m losing my mind.

It was a cartoon and i think it was a kids show.

And i don’t know if this is the same show but I remember an episode of a superhero boy and girl saving their school from like a substitute lunch lady who wanted to take the kids brains??? I’ve been searching so long for these.

This was like years ago maybe would have aired back in like 2008-2013ish?? And aired in the USA.
I’m 99% sure it was 2D animation and in English (at least where I watched it).

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Do you remember which TV channel you watched it on? If you do, you might have a chance at narrowing down the search by looking for a list of all the shows they aired (on Wikipedia for example). It would be a good start.

Comment: It maybe was Nickelodeon, Disney channel?, Cartoon Network, ? Pbs? I don’t remember but it was in this ballpark of shows directed towards kids/teens

Comment: Do these look familiar? https://d2ykdu8745rm9t.cloudfront.net/cover/i/009/201/836/tumblr_static_76e4eee014944a2ce650b11cbb441001-7250.jpg?rect=1,0,497,497&q=98&fm=jpg&fit=max | https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/861/400/png-clipart-timmy-turner-mr-crocker-cosmo-wanda-cartoon-others-text-friendship.png I have a feeling I saw a similar thermometre scene in some cartoon a while ago, although I might be mixing stuffs up.